# How to compare two strings of array in java?

Tags: java

The if statement does not read the string in the array - tokens[i] so the condition after if does not execute. The string "hot" can not be read. Why is that so? Please help! Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String str = "Wow! It's getting realy hot in here." ;
    String delims = "[ .,?!/><;:'_!`~/$/@/#/%/&/|/[/]/{/}/)/(]+";
    String[] tokens = str.split(delims);

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
        if (tokens[i] == "hot"){

            System.out.println("Found!");
            break;
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Not found!");
        }
   }     

}
```

Comment: Compare strings with `equals`, not with `==`.

Comment: Similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: Nooooooooooo.. please nooooooooo :___(

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`String.equals(String otherString)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) function to compare strings.

```
if (tokens[i].equals("hot")){
```

Not the `==` operator.

The reason is that `==` just compares object references/primitives,where as String's [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method checks equality.

Comment: @Suresh ok it worked fine. Now I have to edit my code so that only "Found" is displayed when the string "hot" is discovered in the text. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because you are using the `==`-Operator for comparing `String`s.

The `==`-Operator checks whether the object reference is the same. This is not the case, because `"hot"` is not the same reference as `tokens[i]`.

`Object.equals()` compares the values of the object. For a `String`, it compares if the character combination is the same. Check the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for more information.

So, use `tokens[i].equals(String str)`.

If case sensitivity doesn't matter, use this method: `string.eqaulsIgnoreCase(String anotherString`).

Comment: Yes I get it. Thanks lot for the clear info. Tried it and it worked fine.